# How to monitor memory usage on heroku (node.js)

Tags: node.js, memory, heroku

There is *New Relic* for *Rails*, but I could not find anything available for *node.js*. Is there any tool or an API to monitor memory usage of heroku dynos?

Comment: when you find it please post back here - we decided against using node based on the fact that we couldn't monitor it (at the time - 6 months ago) effectively on Heroku to decide if/when we need to scale. We got in touch with NR who had nothing to say about it at the time.

Comment: Support stuff said there is no official tool or API however you could make use of `heroku run /proc/*/statm` (I didn't figure it out myself yet)

Comment: @celalo use [node-usage](https://github.com/arunoda/node-usage) which is based on /proc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [node-usage](https://github.com/arunoda/node-usage), additionally you can see the CPU usage too.

Answer (score 4):

This may not be the full solution you're looking for, but you can get the current memory usage of a Node.js process via [`process.memoryUsage()`](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_memoryusage).

Comment: Could you tell how the values can be used? I see, we have rss, headTotal and heapMaster? How can I calculate this to MB and how is this related to the 512 MB RAM of a dyno?

Comment: This SO post explains the values: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12023359/what-do-the-return-values-of-node-js-process-memoryusage-stand-for

Answer (score 1):

Although not as full-featured as New Relic, the `nodetime` npm package (and matching site) does provide memory usage, latency and similar monitoring.