# Why does nodejs memory keeps on growing in this test?

Tags: node.js, memory, memory-leaks

I am trying to get a better understanding of memory consumption in node.js. I've created a small test script that does:

- every second: log current memory consumption
- after 5 seconds: every 10 seconds: create a big JS object
- after 10 seconds: every 10 seconds: delete that big JS object

[Here is the script](https://gist.github.com/askmike/8183593).

So it only ever has a single big object to keep track of, and between deleting it there is 5 seconds before it creates a new one.

How come the memory keeps on growing?

Comment: What memory?  Virtual memory the process is using or the percentage of the max. heap that is consumed by objects?

Comment: I see now from the script that you are checking the process's memory resident memory footprint.

Comment: `delete` does not free the memory for the object - garbage collection does. V8 decides when to do GC, usually only when low on memory to avoid pauses.

Comment: Short: I am logging RSS as reported by `process`. Long: I am trying to prevent "FATAL ERROR: JS Allocation failed - process out of memory" ( https://github.com/askmike/gekko/issues/101 )

Comment: @IvanVergiliev so how can I debug memory consumption? And how does the GC know when to clean?

Comment: I haven't worked with any good tool, but you can take a look at these: http://strongloop.com/strongblog/how-to-heap-snapshots/ https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/11/tracking-down-memory-leaks-in-node-js-a-node-js-holiday-season/    
I think the error you're seeing should only happen if your active working set is larger than available memory, so GC can't free enough space.

Comment: And you can also check this out: http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/ if you want to understand delete better.

Comment: Thanks will take a look. FYI: I made the intervals smaller and a now after a few min I am at 550MB memory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `delete candles;` doesn't work. `delete` deletes properties and `candles` is not one. Switch it with `candles = []`

Comment: Note also, you may want to think about using `"use strict";` since that would throw a syntax-error for this case.

Comment: or use `--use_strict` flag

Answer (score 10):

Perhaps you are not measuring the best metric.

According to the API doc page, `process.memoryUsage()` returns 3 properties:

1. `rss`
2. `heapTotal`
3. `heapUsed`

http://www.nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_memoryusage

rss is the operating system level measure of memory being used.  node.js will lazily expand its heap the max. heap size as needed (very similar to Java).  It grows, but never shrinks.  This is ok for 2 reasons:

1. node manages its memory internally
2. the garbage collector eventually frees memory used by unreferenced objects.
3. there is an upper cap on the size of the heap.  I know it was 1.4 GB at some point, but that may not be accurate any more.  Sorry I am not up-to-date on these details of node.

Freeing does not free at the OS allocator level, but just marks that memory in node's (V8 actually) memory manager as available for other objects.

If you measure the `heapUsed` property instead of `rss`, you should see it go up as objects are allocated and down as the GC runs.

If your goal is to avoid your code from running out of heap space, then that metric is exactly what you need.

If your goal is avoid the node process running out of memory by the OS denying it memory, then  technically rss is the correct metric, but I don't think it will help you.  This isn't a leak.  You simply don't have 1.4 GB (or whatever the current limit is) of memory available to give to the process.  Either the box itself is underpowered or you have a configured resource constraint (like ulimit on Linux systems).

*TL;DR*

If you are worried about new object creations failing in JavaScript code due to memory not being reclaimed, then `heapUsed` is the right metric to capture.  If you are worried about the OS refusing to give the node process more memory, then you either do not have enough memory or there is a software setting preventing more memory.

Comment: Thanks for the explenation. So I am now logging heapUsed and I also upped the numbers a bit: https://gist.github.com/askmike/8183593 . heapUsed is also growing "MEMORY: 361.4034118652344 MB" at which point the node process is consuming 100% CPU and the node process is hanging.

Answer (score 3):

From the [delete docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) on MDN:

> delete is only effective on an object's properties. It has no effect on variable or function names.

Your `delete candles` call doesn't do anything. For instance, if you add `console.log(candles.length);`, you can see that it continues to grow constantly.

You should replace your `delete candles` with `candles = [];` to clear all of the candles. Note, it would be a good idea to consider writing your code in strict mode by prepending `"use strict";` to the top of your file. This would have caused your `delete candles;` line to throw a syntax error, making it quite clear that there was a problem.

Comment: What about `candles = null`?

Comment: @Matteo That would unreference it, but if you look at the gist, you’d see that would result in a `TypeError` [on line 18](https://gist.github.com/askmike/8183593#file-gistfile1-txt-L18) in the next timer tick.