# Do NodeJS addons use the Heap?

Tags: node.js, heap-memory, node-addon-api

After reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12023359/what-do-the-return-values-of-node-js-process-memoryusage-stand-for) about the heap, I'm left wondering: do the operations performed in a Node addon context consume that same heap memory?